# Definition of downstream tasks in NLP

Tags: nlp

What does downstream tasks terminology mean in NLP? I saw this terminology used in several articles but I can't understand the idea behind it.

Comment: I think the correct answer is the one refering to supervised tasks that utilize a pre-trained model.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

"Downstream tasks is what the field calls those supervised-learning tasks that utilize a pre-trained model or component". Derived from this blogpost: http://jalammar.github.io/illustrated-bert/

Answer (score 3):

### What is the "downstream task" in NLP

In supervised learning, you can think of "downstream task" as the application of the language model.

### Example

1. article classification: To tell whether the news is fake news? or Patent classification
2. sequence labeling: assigns a class or label to each token in a given input sequence. See wiki page of [sequence labeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_labeling)

### Reference

- [Which tasks are called as downstream tasks?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/28410/which-tasks-are-called-as-downstream-tasks#:%7E:text=In%20the%20context%20of%20self,are%20also%20used%20for%20NLP.)